# How to place all files generated by CMake in a directory

Tags: cmake

Although I have been searching for this answer online for quite some time, I could not find a single answer to this question.
When i run `cmake` on a `CMakeLists.txt` file I have, all the generated files are created next to the project file.

If i add a `-B` arg, the generated files are created within the specified directory.
What is the best way to define that `-B`behavior inside the CMakeLists.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't define it inside CMakeLists.txt and in fact you cannot because it is already determined before CMake code starts running.

The usual way to save preferred configure command line options is via presets: https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html

Comment: Ι think that this will do. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I use that

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${PROJECT_NAME} POST_BUILD
    COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_directory
    ${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/res $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${PROJECT_NAME}>/res)
```